# Migrate mail server

Tags: email, migration

I have an old mail server that I have to migrate to a new server with a different name and IP.

I know how to do that (just copy the maildir directory), but how can I do that without my users having to download all of their messages again?

Comment: It depends on how you authorize them, PAM, Mysql, LDAP or some other method..

Comment: ...which mail server you're using might have an impact, too... :/

Comment: the old server it's : qmail/vpopmail
and on the new server it's : postfix/dovecot

Comment: i read something about the UIDL, do you know how it works?

Comment: Don't move the existing messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem,
the UIDL (mail ID) wasn't on the same format in my both servers

for more info : http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration